# Swift UIView background color opacity

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, alpha

I have a `UIView` with a `UILabel` in it. I want the UIView to have white background color, but with an opacity of 50%. The problem whith setting `view.alpha = 0.5` is that the label will have an opacity of 50% as well, so I figured out that it maybe would be possible to have a `UIView` with white background color and opacity (white_view), and then have another `UIView` with the label (label_view). Then add the "white_view" to "label_view" by doing this: `label_view.addSubview(white_view)`. This apparently doesn't work. I'd like to do like: `label_view.backgroundView(white_view)` but you can't set a background view on a `UIView` like you can do in a `UICollectionView` for instance.

Does anyone have any clue of how to solve this?

**EDIT**
Because several answers are approx the same I'll type it here.
Now I've tried even these:

```
label_view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
label_view1.addSubview(firstPlacelbl)
endGameView.addSubview(label_view1)
```

and

```
label_view1.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
label_view1.addSubview(firstPlacelbl)
endGameView.addSubview(label_view1)
```

And still the label is also affected by the alpha, and it gets an opacity of 50%. I don't get it what I do wrong because I only set the colors alpha to 0.5 and not the labels. Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand that question correctly, you would like to have a half-transparent `UIView` and a non-transparent white-background for the `UILabel` on it. Afaik, `UILabel`s have a completely transparent background by default, so you would have to set its background color to white if you want it to have a background color at all. Thus you do not need a view in between. Also, you can set everything in the Storyboard appropriately, if you use it.

Comment: I want to have a half-transparent `UIView` with white background color, and the label on the top of it (in a new view if it doesn't work in the same). So it's like a half transparent box with a label that is 100% visible. I think @Vitaliy's answer below should work!

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You can set background color of view to the UIColor with alpha, and not affect `view.alpha`:

`view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)`

or

`view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)`

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for. I will try it on Monday when I'm home and let you know!

Comment: You need to set parent UIView background color to UIColor with alpha: `endGameView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)` not your UILabel

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 76):

Setting `alpha` property of a view affects its subviews. If you want just transparent background set view's `backgroundColor` proprty to a color that has alpha component smaller than 1.

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be like @Vitaliy's answer below. I will try this as well and let you know on Monday! Thanks

Comment: Hey please check my edit! I've tried your solution and it doesn't work the way I want it to do!

Comment: swift 3: `UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)`

Comment: That is what I need, to not affect view's subView.

Answer (score 42):

**For Swift 4.x and above**

`yourView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)`

Answer (score 14):

You can also set it from `InterfaceBuilder` by changing color's opacity:

[image]

Comment: This is ideal as changing the alpha on the view itself will trickle down and affect anything within it as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have found is that `view` is different from your `UIView`. 'view' refers to the entire view. For example your home screen is a view.

You need to clearly separate the entire 'view' your 'UIView' and your 'UILabel'

You can accomplish this by going to your storyboard, clicking on the item, Identity Inspector, and changing the `Restoration ID`.

Now to access each item in your code using the restoration ID

Comment: I only use UIViews, like: `var label_view = UIView()', and the views are done programmatically, no story board is used. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple in Swift . just put this color  in your background view color and it will work .

```swift
let dimAlphaRedColor =  UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7)
yourView.backGroundColor =  dimAlphaRedColor
```

Answer (score 0):

**The question is old, but it seems that there are people who have the same concerns.**

What do you think of the opinion that 'the alpha property of UIColor and the opacity property of Interface Builder are applied differently in code'?

---

The two views created in Interface Builder were initially different colors, but had to be the same color when the conditions changed.
So, I had to set the background color of one view in code, and set a different value to make the background color of both views the same.

As an actual example, the background color of Interface Builder was 0x121212 and the Opacity value was 80%*(in **Amani Elsaed**'s image :: Red: 18, Green: 18, Blue: 18, Hex Color #: [121212], Opacity: 80)*,
In the code, I set the other view a background color of 0x121212 with an alpha value of 0.8.

```
self.myFuncView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 18, green: 18, blue: 18, alpha: 0.8)
```

extension is

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0,
                  green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0,
                  blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0,
                  alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

However, the actual view was

- 'View with background color specified in Interface Builder': R 0.09 G 0.09 B 0.09 alpha 0.8.
- 'View with background color by code': R 0.07 G 0.07 B 0.07 alpha 0.8

Calculating it,

- 0x12 = 18(decimal)
- 18/255 = 0.07058...
- 255 * 0.09 = 22.95
- 23(decimal) = 0x17

So, I was able to match the colors similarly by setting the UIColor values ​​to 17, 17, 17 and alpha 0.8.

```
self.myFuncView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 17, green: 17, blue: 17, alpha: 0.8)
```

Or can anyone tell me what I'm missing?